# Convert string to JSON and get value

Tags: java, android, json, string

I have this string:

```
{"markers":[{"tag":"1","dep":"2"}]}
```

How to convert it to JSON and get value `tag` and `dep`?

Comment: use volley for get json

Answer (score 1):

you need **JSONObject** to do this

```
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        String tag, dep;

        JSONArray jArray = response.getJSONArray("markers");
        JSONObject msg = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
        tag = msg.getString("tag");
        dep = msg.getString("dep");
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry, what is parameter response type, there is not be initiate ... thanks a lot Webster..

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json_str);
JSONArray array= object.getJSONArray("markers");

for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
{
JSONObject obj= array.getJSONObject(i);
String tag= obj.getString("tag");
int dep= obj.getInt("dep");

}

}catch(JSONException e){


}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you may find your solution. Try it.

```
try {
    //jsonString : {"markers": [{"tag":"1","dep":"2"}]}
    JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray uniArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("markers");
    JSONObject subObject = uniArray.getJSONObject(0);
    String tag = subObject.getString("tag");
    String dep = subObject.getString("dep");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's good habbit to serialize the json to pojo object ..

here you can use Gson (a google library to serialize/deserialize json to pojo object)

> Assuming you are using Android-Studio IDE for android development

Step 1 : add this gson dependency on build.gradle file of module scope

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```

Step 2: create model for json

```
{"markers":[{"tag":"1","dep":"2"}]}
```

**Markers.java**

```
public class Markers {
/**
 * tag : 1
 * dep : 2
 */

private List<MarkersEntity> markers;

public void setMarkers(List<MarkersEntity> markers) {
    this.markers = markers;
}

public List<MarkersEntity> getMarkers() {
    return markers;
}

public static class MarkersEntity {
    private String tag;
    private String dep;

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public void setDep(String dep) {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public String getDep() {
        return dep;
    }
  }
}
```

Step 3: serialise json string to pojo object using gson

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Markers markers = gson.fromJson(<jsonstring>.toString(), Markers.class);
```

Step 4: iterate the markers.getMarkersEntity() to get values of tag & dep

```
for(MarkersEntity data:markers.getMarkersEntity())
{
     String tag = data.getTag();
     String dep = data.getDep();
     Log.d("JSON to Object", tag +"-"+dep);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ion Library for this and parse it as follows:

```
Ion.with(MainActivity.this).load("url").asJsonObject().setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception arg0, JsonObject arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arg0==null)
            {
                arg1.get("markers").getAsJsonArray();
                JsonObject Jobj=arg1.getAsJsonObject();
                String tag=Jobj.get("tag").getAsString();
                String dep=Jobj.get("dep").getAsString();
            }

        }
    });
```